# How a new link is created/deleted for each post in CMS like Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, content-management-system

I want to create a custom Content Management System , and I'm wondering about the posts part , I know that there is a form for creating posts and then these data are added to a database and then printed to a link like (example.com/blog/a-post-link) , I'm wondering how this like is created and then deleted .

Is these is for example a php file that pulls the post data from the database like "post.php" and then passing the post id or something like that to the file like 'post.php?id=1' and then this is redirected using .htaccess to a like like "example.com/blog/a-post-link"?

I hope I explained the question well , and if not ask me about anything that is not clear.

Comment: Its *virtual*, rewrites are used to pass `/anything/page` to the script, and then the script matches it with a page slug in the database. I built a couple of CMS's for giggles, even [one you code in](https://github.com/lcherone/cloud-developer).

Comment: When a post is saved, just take the title, slugify it (there are multiple libraries for this) and store it in the database with the post. Then when someone accesses the URL `/some-url`, take the `some-url` part and fetch the post from the database that matches the slug instead of the id.

Comment: So it will be for example "post.php/title=post-title" then I use .htaccess to change it to "blog/post-title"?